# Rails and RSpec: ActionController::UnknownFormat error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have been trying to test Paperclip file uploads using RSpec with Rails.

When I run the server, I have no problems, but when I run my (very basic) RSpec test, I receive the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: visit root_path

 ActionController::UnknownFormat:
   PhotosController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

   request.formats: ["text/html"]
   request.variant: []
```

Here is my test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

    feature 'photos' do

      context 'no photos have been added' do

        scenario 'should display prompt to add a photo' do
          visit root_path
          expect(page).to have_content 'No photos yet'
          expect(page).to have_link 'Add a photo'
        end

      end

    end
```

Here is my view in haml:

```
- if @photos.any?
  - @photos.each do |photo|
    = image_tag photo.image
    = photo.caption
- else
  %h1 No photos yet


%h2= link_to "Add a photo", new_photo_path
```

Here is my photo model:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  validates :image, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

I had some problems with a NoMethodError in my test saying that `has_attached_file` was unrecognized, but after Googling extensively I found someone had luck by adding a paperclip.rb file to config/initializers with the following:

```
require "paperclip/railtie"

Paperclip::Railtie.insert
```

Any idea why I might be experiencing this issue, and how I might overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you it can't find the template handler for the view. Since you're using Haml as the handler, you have to add the haml gem to your gem file.

Comment: Thanks but it was in there already, the views loaded fine when I ran the server.

Comment: Did you restart your server after you ran bundle install?

Comment: You might also need to stop spring (`spring stop`) for the haml gem to be taken into account in tests.